# MySQL condition in where-clause of a JPA named query with nullable attribute as parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa

How can a condition be specified in a where-clause of a JPA named query for a MySQL 5.1 database, in case some of the attributes which are passed as parameter are nullable?

Example: The table contains attribute_1 which is nullable and attribute_2 which is not nullable. The contents are:

```
    id    attribute_1    attribute_2
    --    -----------    -----------
    1     {null}          123
    2     X               456
```

The query result should be record 1 if :param_1 = null AND :param_2 = "123"

The query result should be record 2 if :param_1 = "X" AND :param_2 = "456"

The query should have no result if for example :param_1 = "X" AND :param_2 = "123"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a native query. I cannot get it work with a JP-QL query.
I used the condition

```
AND IF(?1 IS NULL, b.attribute_1 IS NULL, b.attribute_1 = ?1)
```

in the where clause (?1 is the placeholder for the parameter).

Answer (score 0):

For your first row, you need to change the where clause in your query:

```
where attribute_1 is null
```

Using `=` instead would yield no rows, since `a = null` is always `null`.

Comment: It's not that simple. In a named query the where-clause might for example look like `WHERE table.attribute_1 = :param_1 and table.attribute_2 = :param_2`. The problem is that :param_1 might be the the Java null value.

Comment: Yep, I figured as much. But you've no workaround doing so. If `:param_1` is null then pass `attribute_1 is null`, else `attribute_1 = :param_1`. Different statements. You could combine/OR the two with a condition on `:param_1` but doing so will damage your query plan if the statement is prepared.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Passing a string like `attribute_1 is null` is not possible. And id does not solve the problem, because the query cannot be formulated in a way that `attribute_1 is null` and `attribute_1 = param_1` can be filled in correctly. I solved the problem in an other way, see next answer.

Comment: What I'm saying is that, as impossible as it is to change it, your way of doing it (aka sending `attr1 = var1` when `var1` is null) *cannot* and *will not* return a row. Ever. Either conditionally send your query based on the attribute's value as initially suggested. Or use `where (attr1 = var1 or var1 is null)` instead as subsequently suggested -- but be aware that the latter *cannot* and *will not* use any applicable index on `attr1` if prepared.

Comment: Your statement "[...]your way of doing it[...] cannot and will not return a row" confuses me. I did not state a solution for my problem in the question or in these comments at all... (I stated a solution/workaround in my own answer below). Anyway thanks for your efforts.